# Contents Inside paper-header-panel getting overlapped in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I've got a `paper-header-panel` inside `body`. content fits 100% below the header(added `fit` class). In chrome (version 48.* 64bit) the divs inside the content div are getting overlapped because of height getting automatically set to `0px`. Everything was working fine before updating to v48. I've checked in Chromium, Firefox, opera and safari also and it is working as expected. If I resize the window everything gets fixed. I assume this is because of the `iron-resize-behavior`. I can solve this by manually setting the height for each inner div but I'm not able to figure out what is the reason behind this, bug with chrome/polymer polyfill not keeping up with browser changes.

In Firefox

[image: Desired(in firefox)]

In chrome

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Template me</title>

    <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>

    <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
    <link rel="import" href="iron-elements/iron-elements.html">
    <link rel="import" href="gold-email-input/gold-email-input.html">

</head>

<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">

  
    
  <paper-header-panel class="flex">
    <paper-toolbar>
      <div>Hello World!</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div class="fit layout vertical">
        <div class="horizontal layout">
          <div class="flex">Item One left</div>
          <div>Item One right</div>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal layout">
          <div class="flex">Item Two left</div>
          <div>Item Two right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </paper-header-panel>
  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First try to include `polymer.html` and then use `webcomponentsjs`.

Comment: @Dmitry check in chrome version 48.* .  I don't think this has anything to do with the order, how would you justify the behavior in other browsers(including chromium and other webkit browsers) then ?

Comment: webcomponent polyfills designed to add support for browsers to those things that they do not support. This is one of the solutions to your problems. Maybe you need to include [iron flex layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) for work with flex

Comment: What solution? I've already included `iron-elements` which imports `iron-flex-layout`.

Comment: The example of your code is work perfect in my Chrome, version 46 64-bit. Maybe its a Chrome 48 version bug, I don't know

Comment: @Dmitry Not sure if its a bug with chrome or polymer not updating polyfill to match the chrome changes.